# How to import services installed/deployed in AWS cloud using Cross Account Role in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm developing a platform which is needed to get the deployed/configured services from the AWS cloud. When I have checked with google I got know we need to set-up a third party user with the **cross-platform role.**

**Scenario:**

consider In my AWS account have configured s3, Cognito, ec2, load balancer, Dynamodb, etc. I want to make an engine to get the user deployed services from the AWS using python programming.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the requirements?

Comment: @manoj Rana updated